# Alter resolution of an image to match a certain pixel density (DPI)

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am working on a HTML5 canvas where I am manipulating certain graphics and text using javascript. I want to include a print preview feature to display how the canvas would look like when printed. I am converting the canvas into an image using the following code, and will later be using the image for print preview.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

As the printer would be able to printing at  a pixel density of 260dpi, I would like to have `img` match the pixel density of the printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You need the print size to set the DPI

The canvas is dimensionless. Without a known fixed dimension dots per inch is meaningless.

You can print a 240 by 240 canvas at 240dpi by printing it to be 1 by 1inch in size. That very same canvas will also be 24dpi if you print it to be 10 by 10 inches.

If you want the the pixel density of the canvas to match some DPI you need to set the canvas resolution to match a known print size, and when you print the canvas you must specify that size or the DPI will not match.

### Example. Set canvas resolution to match known print size and dpi

To print a canvas to fit an A4 page at 240dpi

```
const A4_PAGE_SIZE = {width: 8.27, height: 11.69); // in inches
const DPI = 240;  
canvas.width = A4_PAGE_SIZE.width * DPI;   // ~1984px
canvas.height = A4_PAGE_SIZE.height * DPI; // ~2805px
```

Now render the canvas content to fit the new canvas resolution, and convert to PNG. You can then print the image at 240 dpi by setting the print size to be 8.27 by 11.69 inches.

**Note** If you are not rendering the canvas content (eg the content is a loaded image) then you should match the canvas size to the image size, making the canvas resolution higher (or lower) than the original image will decrease the print quality as the scaling used by the canvas 2D API is not designed for print.

**Note** The PNG image format does let you specify the physical size of the PNG image by setting pixels per meter rather than the total pixels in the header. However you can not do this via the native canvas API. You will need to use a 3rd party PNG encoder to set this header info.